# Why are my container contents overflowing?

Tags: html, css

I made a container aligned vertically and horizontally to the center of the page containing  3 elements (left panel, right panel and output) in front of the background div. However I'm trying to adjust the height to fill the whole page, but it overflows and creates a scrollbar I'm trying to avoid. I tried height:100vh and height:100% but both won't work, because contents still go below be page. I'm not sure what caused this and what I did wrong. I also tried few solutions from other answers out there, but they didn't fix my issue.

```css
.body-background{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background-image: url(assets/background.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.calc-base{ 
  width:40vw;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: azure;
  margin:0;
}
.output{
  height:10vh;
  border:3px solid rgb(255, 150, 150);
}
.container {
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
  gap: 0px 0px; 
  min-height: 100%
}
.left-panel { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 4 / 3; 
  border-left:3px solid rgb(0, 179, 255);
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(158, 13, 255);
  float: left;    
  height: 100vh;
}
.right-panel { grid-area: 1 / 3 / 4 / 4;
  border-bottom: solid 3px black;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
  border-left:3px solid black;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-background">
  <div class="calc-base">
    <div class="output">w</div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="left-panel">
          &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="right-panel">
          &nbsp;
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div>
<div>
```

Comment: If the right panel is the height of the viewport, and you have a header above it, then "the height of the viewport" + "height of the header" has to be more than "the height of the viewport".

Comment: I tried changing the values, but even then I'm left with few pixels border overflow and a scroll. It's confusing

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do everything you want with just Flexbox.   For this you need two containers 1) body-background for the column layout and 2) container for the left-right row layout.   I hope this helps.

From here you can use the flex-grow options to grow and shrink cells to take up space.

```css
body, div { 
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.body-background{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background-image: url(assets/background.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.output{
  height:10vh;
  width: 100%;
  border:3px solid rgb(255, 150, 150);
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.left-panel { 
   border: 3px solid black;
   flex-grow: 1;
}
.right-panel {
  border: 3px solid black;
  flex-grow: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-background">
    <div class="output">w</div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="left-panel">
        &nbsp;
      </div>
      <div class="right-panel">
        &nbsp;
      </div>
    </div>
  <div>
<div>
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not the answer I was looking for. I specifically used grid for this task. I modified your answer for my needs, but I prefer more suitable solution.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to use grid?